# We throw a symmetric coin 3 times, then we roll the dice the amount of times the head appeared

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We throw a symmetric coin 3 times, then we roll the dice the amount of times the head appeared. What is the probability of:

i) we roll at least one "6"

ii) We throw exactly 3 heads, if we know we rolled at least one "6"

---

So let $A =$ we rolled at least one "6", then $A^c = $ there is zero "6", $B_i = $ we throw i heads

i)

then: $P(A) = \sum_{i=0}^{3}P(A|B_i) =1-  \sum_{i=0}^{3}P(A^c|B_i) = 1  - (\frac 12 \frac{5}{6} + \frac14(\frac{5}{6})^2 +\frac18(\frac56)^3) $

ii)

$P(B_3|A) = \frac {P(A|B_3)P(B_3)}{P(A)} =\frac {(1-P(A^c|B_3))P(B_3)}{P(A)}$ and we have everything.

It is correct?

Comment: I'm worried about the work in (i). Did you leave out factors $P(B_i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a). Let us consider the probability that the dice rolls a $6$ at least one time:
$$P(\textrm{dice}=6,k\geq1)=1-P(\textrm{dice}=6,k=0)$$
We just have to compute that it never happens. This is accomplished by considering all cases:
$$P(\textrm{dice}=6,k=0)=\sum_{j=0}^3P(\textrm{dice}=6,k=0|\textrm{H}=j)P(\textrm{H}=j)$$
$$P(H=j)=\binom{3}{j}0.5^j(1-0.5)^{3-j}=\binom{3}{j}0.5^3$$
where $P(H=j)$ is the probability of getting $j$ heads in our three throws. The conditional is:
$$P(\textrm{dice}=6,k=0|\textrm{H}=j)=\binom{j}{0}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)^0\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{j-0}=\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{j}$$
So in the end we get
$$P(\textrm{dice}=6,k=0)\approx 0.77$$
$$P(\textrm{dice}=6,k\geq 1)\approx 0.23$$

(b).
$$P(H=3|\textrm{dice}=6,k\geq1)=\frac{P(\textrm{dice}=6,k\geq1|H=3)P(H=3)}{P(\textrm{dice}=6,k\geq1)}$$

Comment: But what about $j=0$. Then $P(dice=6,k=0|H=0) = 1$? It should not be $0$?

Comment: The probability of rolling $6$ zero times is $1$ if we never got heads in the coin tosses